# Single vs. double quotes in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Consider:

```
ghci> :t 'a'
'a' :: Char
ghci> :t "a"
"a" :: [Char]
```

Why is it treating single and double quotes differently, and is that important?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is just like C/C++/C#/Java and other programming languages. Single quotes means single character, double quotes means character array (string).

In Haskell, `'c'` is a single character (`Char`), and `"c"` is a list of characters (`[Char]`).

You can compare this to integers and lists of integers:

```
ghci> let a = 1
ghci> let b = [1,2,3]
ghci> :t a
a :: Integer
ghci> :t b
b :: [Integer]
```

It is important because there has to be a distinction between single elements and a list of elements. You can perform different operations on simple elements, and different operations on lists.

Comment: Maybe something important to note would be `:info String` prints out `type String = [Char]`, so you can see explicitly how the `String` type is defined.

Answer (score 1):

They're interpreted differently because they just are (that's just how the language is defined). This is important because a `Char` and a `[Char]` aren't the same thing. Other than that I'm not sure what you're trying to ask here.